# Curl Save Download with Extension Determined by Content-type

Tags: curl

I'm trying to download ~10'000 files using the Windows command prompt which are a mix of pdf, png and xml.

They can be requested from a server with sequential number requests without a file name or extension (ie `example.com/files/2550/file` gives me the same file as `example.com/files/2550/differentName`).

I've written the below script which gets me 90% of the way there, but basically saves all the files with the pdf extension (even if they are images or excel sheets):

```
curl --cookie "JSESSIONID=keyremoved" -o "#1.pdf" https://website.net/file/[0001-9999]/file
```

I've tried using -oj, however that uses the content-disposition, which in this case the server doesn't provide a response to.

**Any ideas on how I can set the file extension based on the content-type?**

Example server output for an excel sheet:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Date: Sun, 19 Aug 2018 23:38:28 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Pragma: Public
Cache-Control: max-age=0
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Content-Length: 623763
```

Comment: Would [--remote-name](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-O) be an option for you?

Comment: I believe `--remote-name` uses the last part of the URL, and since this is just any random string that I type, it won’t be useful in determining file type. `--remote-header-name` also doesn’t work as per my original post.